# Block records from updating

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables

**tbl_orders**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_orders (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    customer_name character varying NOT NULL,
    is_archived boolean NOT NULL
);
```

**tbl_order_items**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_order_items (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    product_name character varying NOT NULL,
    quantity integer NOT NULL,
    order_id int NOT NULL
);
```

In my application I have the possibility to archive an order, which set the boolean isArchived to true to that order record. The order record can have multiple order items which I want to prevent from being updated when the order has the boolean isArchived set to true. Do I have to set an isArchived boolean on the order items level?

Is this possible to prevent this on database level?

Comment: One option is to create trigger (before update) for tbl_order_items that checks tbl_orders is_archive flag for not doing update – https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on `tbl_order_items` `FOR EACH ROW` that throws an error when the order `NEW.order_id` is archived.

That is the most elegant and normalized solution, but it requires that a trigger runs whenever a row in `tbl_order_items` is updated.